# Have controlled loops in a single terraform resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, nested-loops, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create subnets based on the user inputs let's say 4(var.number_of_private_subnets). I want them to be in distinct Availability Zones (Az). I have observed that Terraform sometimes makes use of all the available Az's and sometimes it doesn't. so for this reason I don't want to leave it for terraform to pick the AZ's

```
data aws_availability_zones "azs"{
  state = "available"

}
```

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count                = var.number_of_private_subnets
  cidr_block           = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main_vpc.cidr_block,8, count.index )
  vpc_id               = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
  availability_zone    = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[count.index]


    tags   = {
      Name = "${var.env_name}-PrivateSubnet-${count.index+1}"
    }
}
```

This code fails if the available az's for the particular `aws_region` are 3 , it would try to access the 4th element form the list as the user input is 4.

Is there anyway where I can create 4 subnets controlling the `availability_zone` in such a way the subnets span across all the available zones?

Comment: The configuration you showed here is risky for future maintenance: AWS can add and remove availability zones over time, which could cause the names to appear at different `count.index` positions, which would then cause Terraform to believe you intend to change the availability zone for an existing subnet, which is a change that requires deleting and then re-creating the subnet. I think it'd be safer to use `for_each` instead of `count` and to create subnets across all of the available AZs, even if you don't intend to use them all today, so that future additions can't impact existing subnets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%`):

```
  availability_zone    = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[count.index % 3]
```

or better yet,

```
  availability_zone    = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names[count.index % len(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)]
```

---

Also, for anyone just jumping straight to the answers, be sure to read the comment from Martin Atkins on the question.